# App crash, not sure what the error is pointing me too

Tags: java, android

Whenever I run this program in Andriod studio The app just cashes on the phone.

```
package com.example.homework1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    double tipPercent;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView tipAmountString;
    double tipAmountCalc;
    TextView totals;
    EditText BaseBillTotal;
    EditText TipValue;


    double baseValueCalc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TipValue = findViewById(R.id.TipValue);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        tipAmountString = findViewById(R.id.tipAmountString);
        totals = findViewById(R.id.TotalValueScreen);
        BaseBillTotal = findViewById(R.id.BillBaseValue);
        baseValueCalc = Double.parseDouble(BaseBillTotal.getText().toString());









        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                tipAmountString.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                tipAmountCalc = progress*.10;

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.tipPercentGroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.radioButton){
                    tipPercent = .10;

                }

                    else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2){
                    tipPercent = .15;

                }

                    else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton3){
                    tipPercent = .18;
                }
                    else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton4)
                {

                    tipPercent = tipAmountCalc;


                }


            }
        });
        TipValue.setText(String.valueOf(tipPercent*100));
        totals.setText(String.valueOf(tipPercent * baseValueCalc) );
    }
}
```

This is the error in the console
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.homework1, PID: 7027
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.homework1/com.example.homework1.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
at com.example.homework1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace explains exactly what is breaking and why:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText at com.example.homework1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)`

line 32 of your `MainActivity` is `BaseBillTotal = findViewById(R.id.BillBaseValue);`

You have `BaseBillTotal` defined in your Activity as an `EditText`, but according to this exception, your layout file has a `ConstraintLayout` with an id of `BillBaseValue`, and you can't cast that to an `EditText`. Double check your layout file and verify the type and ID there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `id` of your edit texts. According to the error you might have given the constraint layout the id of `BillBaseValue` or `TipValue` instead of the actual edit text in your xml layout.